# Executing custom action after showing the UI in wix installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.5, deferred-execution

I have written a custom action which i want to execute after showing the UI of  Next dialog to the user.
Then I want to show the next dialog after execution of that custom action without any next button.
The scenario is like, on click of Next Button of previous dialog. Firstly, next dialog should appear and then the custom action should get executed while showing the UI to the user and when it completes its execution, the UI of Next Dialog should be shown without clicking on Next Button.

Comment: I am stuck, please help.

Comment: What you described sound pretty tricky. If you explain the initial intention of that approach, people might know how to help you.